# What is the word meaning between type and function name?

Tags: c

For example,

```
static int some_words_in_question some_function(){
     return 0;
}
```

what's the meaning and the purpose of `some_words_in_question` in C programming?
If you need more sample because you still don't understand what I ask, you can see on Linux Kernel source code.

Comment: A more concrete example would be helpful here.  But it's likely to be the calling convention or something like that.

Comment: Probably a GCC extension or something. Afaik the Linux kernel sources make heavy use of those.

Comment: What do you refer to? `asmlinkage` ?

Answer (score 4):

Although some examples would be good, I suppose you refer to compiler specific extensions. These can be calling conventions for the function (defining how the function is to be called in the actual machine code) or other extensions specifying some special property of the function or declaration. As these are completely compiler-specific they are not part of the standard C language and often refer to platform-dependent properties regarding the actual compiled machine code.